# Eclipse FormEditor button as page title

Tags: tabs, eclipse-plugin

I implemented my custom FormEditor. Now I want to let user create new FormPages (a.k.a. tabs) in this editor like it is made e.g. in Chrome tabs. How to insert a "new tab" button near the titles of existing FormPages?

Thank you in advance!

UPD:
I added a FormPage with title "+" and insert new page in listener to PageChangedEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add actions to the toolbar at the top right of a `FormPage` like this:

```java
ScrolledForm form = managedForm.getForm();

IToolBarManager manager = form.getToolBarManager();

Action myAction = new Action("My Action") {
    public void run() {
        // TODO your action
    }
};

myAction.setToolTipText("tooltip text");
myAction.setImageDescriptor(action image descriptor);

manager.add(myAction);
```

Comment: That's not what i want. Action should be in the same panel with FormPage titles (bottom of FormEditor).